# SublimeRepl New Repl "No Repl for 'sql' "

Tags: postgresql, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm trying to set up a Sublime Text Repl for Postgres using Sublime Repl.

I've set up a new folder in `Users/Packages/SublimeRepl/config` called `Postgres` and added two files:

`Main.sublime-menu` has the following content

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "R",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"command": "repl_open", 
                 "caption": "PSQL",
                 "id": "repl_psql",
                 "mnemonic": "Q",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": {"windows": "$win_cmd_encoding",
                                 "linux": "utf-8",
                                 "osx": "utf-8"},
                    "cmd": {"windows": ["psql.exe", "-a"],
                            "linux": ["psql","-U","tahnoon"],
                            "osx": ["psql","-U","tahnoon"]},
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "env": {},
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/SQL/SQL.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
            ]   
        }]
    }
]
```

and `Default.sublime-commands` has the following content

```
[
    {
        "caption": "SublimeREPL: PSQL",
        "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
            "id": "repl_psql",
            "file": "config/Postgres/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
    }
]
```

If I launch a repl and try and Eval from a file called `test.sql` with `Ctrl+,F` I get an error message `Cannot Find Repl for 'sql'`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `"id": "repl_sql"` instead of `"repl_psql"`?

Comment: Hi @MattDMo - thanks for responding. I did and also tried saving the file as test.psql - both had not effect. Same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that the following key-value `"external_id":"sql"` does the trick:

```
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "R",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"command": "repl_open", 
                 "caption": "PSQL",
                 "id": "repl_sql",
                 "mnemonic": "Q",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": {"windows": "$win_cmd_encoding",
                                 "linux": "utf-8",
                                 "osx": "utf-8"},
                    "cmd": {"windows": ["psql.exe","-U","tahnoon"],
                            "linux": ["psql","-U","tahnoon"],
                            "osx": ["psql","-U","tahnoon"]},
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n", 
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "external_id": "sql",
                    "suppress_echo": false, 
                    "syntax": "Packages/SQL/SQL.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
            ]   
        }]
    }
]
```